# Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Vector3' to `bool'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a follow path for a enemy but getting this error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Vector3' to bool'

here my code:

```
 IEnumerator FollowPath(Vector3[] waypoints)
 {
     transform.position = waypoints[0];

     int targetWaypointIndex = 1;
     Vector3 targetWaypoint = waypoints[targetWaypointIndex];

     while (true)
     {

         transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetWaypoint, speed * Time.deltaTime);
         if (transform.position = targetWaypoint) //error comes at this line
         {
             targetWaypointIndex = (targetWaypointIndex + 1) % waypoints.Length;
             targetWaypoint = waypoints[targetWaypointIndex];
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
         }
         yield return null;

     }
 }
```

and here the script used at the tutorial im doing.

[image]

How can I solve this issue and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following line has error:

```
transform.position = targetWaypoint
```

You are assigning value and not comparing, it should be

```
transform.position == targetWaypoint
```

Comment: sometimes all you need is a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: now im getting this error: Array index is out of range.
EnemyGuard.Start () , what is it?

Comment: This means you are trying to access an element which does not exist in that array, for example, your array has 2 elements, and you are trying to access the third element. Since that is a separate issue, you need to ask different question.